# Request signature does not match during bucket creation with ZendService\Amazon\S3

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a bucket with Amazon S3 using ZendService\Amazon S3, but I am receiving the following error:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Here is my Code Snippet:

```
        $s3 = new S3(AWSAccessKeyId,AWSSecretKey); 
        $bucketName = 'bucketname123';
        $buckets    = $s3->getBuckets();
        if (in_array($bucketName, $buckets)) {
            throw new Exception('You already have this bucket');
        }
        $succ = $s3->createBucket($bucketName);
        if ($succ) {
            echo "Bucket created!";
        } else {            
            echo "Unable to create bucket!";
        }
```

I have double checked my credentials are correct, what could I be missing?

Comment: You're 100% sure you don't have any spaces in any of the keys?

Comment: I found the solution the credentials are correct but the error is in date. So I add the x-amz-date header in the request. 
$headers['x-amz-date'] = $this->getRequestDate();  I added this part in S3.php file of ZendService\Amazon.